# Ldap Query To retrieve users from nested OU

Tags: active-directory, nested, active-directory-group

I am trying to retrieve users from nested ou Group.

Here is the groups organized, we have users members of GroupA, GroupB and so on..

```
OU=Groups
    |- OU=MW
            |
            |-CN=GroupA
            |-CN=Group B
            |-CN=Group C
            |-CN=Group D
```

How do I retrieve users from `Group A` to `Group D` in single ldap query?

I tried to use following, but didn't help:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=OU=MW,OU=Groups,DC=mycompany,DC=com)
```

and

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:CN=U=OMW,OU=Groups,DC=mycompany,DC=com)
```

When I use specific group, I'm able to retrieve users from that group as follows, but I want to query from OU=MW, so that if groupB has nested groups like B1 and B2, I should be able to retrieve it.

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupA,OU=OMW,OU=Groups,DC=exelonds,DC=com)
```